# "by the sounds of it" VS "by the sound of it"

Tags: phrase-usage

> "It's no good nagging me, it's done," he said firmly. "Fred and George have got the gold - spent a good bit of it, too, **by the sounds of it** - and I can't get it back from them and I don't want to. So save your breath, Hermione."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I only find "[by the sound of it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/by-the-sound-of-it-things)" in dictionaries. I suppose "**by the sounds of it**" here means the same as "**by the sound it**". So I'm wondering if "by the sounds of it" is legitimate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown on Google ngram, ***by the sound of it*** is by far the dominant form, but there is an increasing incidence of ***by the sounds of it***. Arguably this originated as an 'error', but its increasing usage and obvious acceptance marks it as an alternative form of the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @SamBC but I'd like to add it seems to me that **by the sound of it** indicates a single source of one's impression whereas **by the sounds of it** indicates many sources. I think the reasoning for the singular being the default dictionary usage is that the speaker is still only expressing one fact or opinion.

To relate back to the example, using **sounds** suggests to me that the speaker learned from many different people, events, posters, etc of the fact that Fred and George "spent a good bit of [the gold]".